# How do I use thenReturn for Class?

Tags: java, mockito, stub

This is a really newbie question but I don't know how to stub this.

I have to mock a method to return Class like this.

```
public Class<? extends SomeClass> getAClass();
```

if I do something like this

```
when(this.someInstance.getAClass())
    .thenReturn(SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass.class);
```

I get compilation error.

```
The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ? extends SomeClass>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ? extends SomeClass>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass>)
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ? extends SomeClass>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ? extends SomeClass>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass>)

Comment: What does the definition of `SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the method declaration can be changed to what @Bohemian suggested above,

```
public <T extends SomeClass> Class<T> getAClass();
```

then you can write your mock statement as follows:

```
when(this.someInstance.<SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass>getAClass())
     .thenReturn(SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass.class);
```

Otherwise, the doReturn semantics should be used as follows:

```
Mockito
    .doReturn(SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass.class)
    .when(this.someInstance.<SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass>getAClass());
```

Comment: What if I can't change the method declaration?

Comment: Then you should use the less type-safe `doReturn()` semantics to escape the compiler error while using `when().thenReturn()` semantics.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the method declaration so that it will work with `thenReturn` then you could use `thenAnswer`:

```
when(this.someInstance.getAClass()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Class<? extends SomeClass>>() {
            @Override
            public Class<? extends SomeClass> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass.class;
            }
});
```

While it isn't ideal to do an implementation of `Answer` just to return a fixed value this should work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing the method:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> Class<T> getAClass();

when(this.someInstance.getAClass())
    .thenReturn(SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass.class);
```

Comment: Then the error is `thenReturn(Class<SomeClass>) is not applicable for arguments Class<SomeClassThatExtendsSomeClass>`.